# Applying changes in django/docker files

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm new at the development with `django` and `docker` and I have a problem when I change a file in the project. My problem is as follows:

I make changes in the content of any file in the `django` project (Template, view, urls) but it does not update in my current running app. Always I want to see my changes I need to restart the server (I'm using `nginx`) doing `docker-compose up`.
Is there a package or a alteration that I should install/do to make it able to accept change in running time?

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir -p /opt/services/djangoapp/src

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /opt/services/djangoapp/src/
WORKDIR /opt/services/djangoapp/src
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

RUN pip install django-livereload 

COPY . /opt/services/djangoapp/src
RUN cd hello && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "config/gunicorn/conf.py", "--bind", ":8000", "--chdir", "hello", "hello.wsgi:application"]
```

Let me know any other information that I might provide to give a better glimpse of the problem (if it is not clear enough).

```
version: '3'

services:

  # database containers, one for each db
  database1:
    image: postgres:10
    volumes:
      - database1_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - config/db/database1_env
    networks:
      - database1_network

  # web container, with django + gunicorn
  djangoapp:
    build: .
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/djangoapp/src
      - static:/opt/services/djangoapp/static
      - media:/opt/services/djangoapp/media
      - .:/code
    networks:
      - database1_network
      - nginx_network
    depends_on:
      - database1

  # reverse proxy container (nginx)
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static:/opt/services/djangoapp/static
      - media:/opt/services/djangoapp/media
    networks:
      - nginx_network
    depends_on:
      - djangoapp

networks:
  database1_network:
    driver: bridge
  database2_network:
    driver: bridge
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  database1_volume:
  static:
  media:
```

Comment: show your docker-compose file

Comment: I just updated my question with my docker-compose file

Comment: still not working after volume mounting?

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty simple. What happens here now

- You have the Dockerfile and you COPY your current folder(**at the time you build your image**) to the container. So while you are running the container it DOES NOT sync with you host(current working folder) if you change something in the host after create the container.
- If you want to sync your host with the container you have to mount it as **volume** with, either `-v` in single container or with `volumes` in docker compose.

> docker run -v /host/directory:/container/directory

```
docker run -v ./:/opt/services/djangoapp/src
```

or using docker-compose if you have multiple containers

```
version: '3'
services:
  web-service:
    build: . # path to Dockerfile
    image: your-image
    volumes:
    - /host/directory:/container/directory
   #- ./:/opt/services/djangoapp/src
```

Comment: I tried running "docker run -v ./:/opt/services/djangoapp/src" however I'm running it inside of the project folder and it gives the error that it requires at least one argument

Comment: I added the part quoted above in the docker-compose, but it still not synchronizing